# npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli, stucking on Compiled 2 Solidity files successfully

Tags: solidity, web3js, npx

npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli, stucking on Compiled 2 Solidity files successfully

My Hardhat.config.js

```
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.9',
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: 'my address',
      accounts: ['my key'],
    },
  },
};
```

My deploy.js

```
const main = async () => {
  const transactionsFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Transactions");
  const transactionsContract = await transactionsFactory.deploy();

  await transactionsContract.deployed();

  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsContract.address);
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

runMain();
```

my transaction.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCount;

    event Transfer(address from, address receiver, uint amount, string message, uint256 timestamp, string keyword);
  
    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(address payable receiver, uint amount, string memory message, string memory keyword) public {
        transactionCount += 1;
        transactions.push(TransferStruct(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword));

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword);
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TransferStruct[] memory) {
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactionCount;
    }
}
```

anyone knows the solution?

I tried to delete cache folder and still didn't work, I also changed the solidity version and didn't work

Comment: I increase the gas limit, then try to replace the nonce,
also didn't work

Comment: You have not mentioned what the problem is!

Comment: stucking, I mentioned it, also on mempool the status is pending

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You don't know web 3? Eth

Comment: saying "stucking" is not a description of a problem. Its not even a word.

Comment: means stuck, status stuck at pending

Comment: Mempool status of the transactions is pending

Comment: It stuck,
you know mempool??

Comment: I'm facing the same problem mate, did you found any solution? looks like it is a problem with goerli network

Comment: same files, contracts, scripts are easily getting deployed on Matic testnet but gerli stucks and sucks xD

Comment: I didn't find a solution, but I tried to increase the gas price and replace the nonce,
it works only one time, I will switch to another network

Comment: The problem is on https://dashboard.alchemy.com/ when creating new app, only goerli available, the other networks are deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to increase your balance then your gas will be increased, the problem was because I have a very low balance so I have low gas